# How to correctly calculate and represent change/delta?

Tags: statistics

I am a software engineer, and I am generating a report of changes in numbers. I would like to know the correct/standard way of calculating, representing, and displaying the change/delta.

For example, let's say a number starts at 100 and drops to 95. How should this change be calculated and displayed?

Additionally, I need a way of representing thresholds of change. For example, if the count drops 10%, that's a major change. I'm guessing this will be closely related to how delta is represented.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the relative error: $(100-95)/100=0.05$ (i.e. $5\%$).

Comment: Let's say the count increases 5%, would it be: (100 - 105)/100 = -0.05? Seems strange that an increase would be represented as a negative number.

Comment: @Andrew You are right, `((new value)-(old value))/(old value)` is more common.

Comment: Use @CareBear's suggestion